# weird python3 import issue, No module named <module>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write some python files like this:

```
main.py
view/   __init__.py #empity file
        MainWindow.py
        ListEditor.py
```

And in each file I wrote those imports:

```
<main.py>
from view.MainWindow import MainWindow
...
```

-

```
<MainWindow.py>
from view.ListEditor import ListEditor
```

and ListEditor.py don't import any files.
Each MainWindow.py or ListEditor.py defines a class that named same as the file name.

when I run the program from main.py, it works. But when I run from MainWindow.py I got ImportError: No module named 'view'

If I write

```
from ListEditor import ListEditor
```

in MainWindow.py, `python MainWindow.py` will be OK. but `python main.py` will get error:
ImportError: No module named 'ListEditor'

So, is there a way to make both `python main.py` and `python MainWindow.py` get right at the same time?

I'm using python3.4

---

**P.S.**

I think I have figured out the problem here. The import command searches a module in sys.path. The sys.path is a group of predefined paths plus the running script path. When I run the code from MainWindow.py, the code `import ListEditor` just works, but when I run from main.py, the current path is set to the parent path. So I need `import view.ListEditor`.
Well, there are couple ways to deal with it. @Vincent Beltman's answer is one of it. Or just put these code in the `__init__.py` file:

```
import os, sys
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(path)
```

Finally, I'm new to python. And I think the import command is quite strange. I thought it should search the files relative to the path of the source file that containing the command, not just relative to the starter file. A starter file may varying and cause troubles like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
try:
    from view.ListEditor import ListEditor # If this one fails
except:
    try:
        from ListEditor import ListEditor # It will try this one
```